# Multi language in parse

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, multilingual

i'm using parse to push notification and I want to sent notification depend on the device language 
the question is How can I send notification in multi language ? there is any way to do this ..!!

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can store the users language selection on the Installation object.

Using iOS examples:

```
PFInstallation *current = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[current setObject:@"english" forKey:@"language"];
[current saveEventually];
```

Then you can push to a query based on language:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query];
[query whereKey:@"language" equalTo:@"english"];

NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"Yo", @"alert", @"yo.caf", @"sound", nil];

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:query];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```